# Как выровнять вторую строчку списка ul li по вертикали с первой?

Tags: css3

line-height не помогает. Есть идеи?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей..

Comment: @Kromster, зачем он тут?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к ul  `list-style-position: outside;`

Comment: list-style-position: outside; не помогло

Comment: Нужно смотреть какие у вас стили применяются к этому списку. Потому что стили по умолчанию для ul - li себя так не ведут

Comment: @Qwertiy очевидно за тем, чтобы был MVCE, а не в комментариях гадали что к чему

Comment: К .widget-menu li a добавил display: inline-block и все норм.